# Changing ObservableCollection at runtime for binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I am generating Grid for every item from my ObservableCollection. Now I want to be able to change the source collection at runtime and I am not sure what needs to be done.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <c:GraphicsList x:Key="GraphicsData" />
</Window.Resources>
...
...
<ItemsControl x:Name="icGraphics" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GraphicsData}}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Tag="{Binding id}"  Margin="15,0,15,15">
              <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding name}"/>
          </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And C#:

```
myCollection1 = this.FindResource("GraphicsData") as GraphicsList;
```

myCollection1:

```
public class GraphicsList : ObservableCollection<Graphics>
{
    public GraphicsList()
    {

    }
}
```

Graphics class:

```
class Graphics: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     // some properties not important
}
```

Its a simplyfied version of my code, but it works, I basically a want to change the source collection myCollection1 to myCollection2 (which is same class just different list). How do I do this?

Comment: you have to change GraphicsData it will reflact on UI

Comment: Create a view model class with a GraphicsList property (with change notification) and bind the ItemsSource to that property.

Comment: Depending on what you're after and when you want it to happen, `icGraphics.ItemsSource = myCollection2` will simply do the trick. You are looking for a solution in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Add or Remove items from collection as below

```
        var dresource = this.Resources["GraphicsData"] as GraphicsList;
        dresource.Add(new Graphics() { Name = "New Entry" });
```

But with StaticResource you can't assign new Collection to one in ResourceDictionary.

Ideally you should be using ViewModel and bind Collection if you want to assign completely new collection.

Your mainwindow class or viewmodel should implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface

Sample code

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private GraphicsList _graphicsData;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    public GraphicsList GraphicsData
    {
        get { return _graphicsData; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _graphicsData)) return;
            _graphicsData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GraphicsData");
        }
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var resource = this.Resources["GraphicsData"] as GraphicsList;


        var resource = new GraphicsList();
        resource.Add(new Graphics(){Name = "Some new Collection of data"});

        this.GraphicsData = resource;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And Your Xaml

```
    <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GraphicsData}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help

Comment: This really helped me, I ditched the static resource and it works. Thanks